# Removing files based on date given in filename

Tags: linux

In a directory, I have some zip files as given below:

```
DBSOURCE20150601.gz
WINDOWS20150504.gz
NETWORK20150609.gz
PATCHTEST20150512.gz
.................
................
```

I want to delete zip files which are older than 10 days based on the date given in filename. For Example,

```
WINDOWS20150604.gz is file having date 4 June 2015.
```

I'm trying with following but not sure why its removing all zip files instead of only 10 days older:

```
ten_days=$(date -d "10 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
for f in *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz; do
  date=${f#*}
  date=${date%.gz}
  (( $date < $ten_days )) && rm "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is not properly extracted from the file name. To do so you need to to do the following

```
    date=${f#*}
    date=${date%.gz}
    date=`echo $date| rev `
    date=${date:0:8}
    date=`echo $date| rev `
```

This date can now be used for comparison and deletion

Comment: Thanks a lot ! specially to address issue of filename itself has numbers other than date.

Answer (score 1):

I think you hoped that in the first row for example the command `date=${f#*}` would remove `DBSOURCE` from the variable `f` because you referenced it by `*[0-9]...[0-9].gz`. You can not use `*` in `date=${f#*}` to have the first portion removed from the variable since `*` is not passed separately into the `for` loop as `DBSOURCE` in this example.

If the filename structure is always the same you can simply use

```
date=${f//[^0-9]/}
```

to remove all non-digit characters (in fact substitute all non-digit characters with 'nothing')

Another way is to use `tr` to extract the date:

```
date=`echo $f|tr -d '[:alpha:] [:punct:]'`
```

Comment: removing all the non numeric characters would not help in the case where filename itself has numbers other than date  - for example WINDOWS8p0OS20150601.gz

Comment: +1 . Thank you ! its working fine but only with files not having numbers in its name other than date, that you too have mentioned.